# How to use WhenAll() when there are parameter dependencies?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

When executing multiple asynchronous tasks, I want to use a `WhenAll()` method so that I can get the benefit of using it: combined error propagation, etc.

Given the following:

```
var item1Task = _service.GetItem1(item1Id);
var item2Task = _service.GetItem2(item2Id);
var item3Task = _service.GetItem3(item3Id);

var allTasks = Task.WhenAll(item1Task, item2Task, item3Task);

try  
{
    await allTasks;
}
catch
{
  ... // some error handling
} 


return new AggregateItems() 
{
  Item1 = item1Task.Result,
  Item2 = item2Task.Result,
  Item3 = item3Task.Result,
}
```

If the parameter, `item3Id` that is passed to `_service.GetItem3(item3Id)` comes from a property of `Item1`, is there a way to still incorporate the `GetItem3()` call in the `WhenAll()` method or must it exist outside of it after the value of `Item1` has been retrieved?

Comment: Answer this to yourself: If `_service.GetItem1(item1Id)` has not yet completed and not yet produced an Item1, how can `_service.GetItem3(item3Id)` run concurrently with `_service.GetItem1(item1Id)` depending on the result of `_service.GetItem1(item1Id)` that doesn't exist yet? Time machine? Wormhole? ;-)

Comment: The call to `WhenAll` in your current code does literally nothing.  Your existing code also runs synchronously, not asynchronously, since you're using `Result` instead of `await`.

Comment: @Servy, ugh, in trying to streamline the code for the post, I removed a necessary line.  Either way, I think that EyesShriveledToRaisins answered my question with his question. I was just wondering if there was any voodoo that could be done. I realize that the dependency forces a synchronous flow.

Answer (score 1):

`async`/`await` is composable. This allows you to have an `async` method that takes as argument a `Task<T>`, and `await`s this task before launching and awaiting the asynchronous operation that depends on the result of the argument. Example:

```
var item1Task = _service.GetItem1(item1Id);
var item2Task = _service.GetItem2(item2Id);
var item3Task = LocalGetItem3(item1Task);

var allTasks = Task.WhenAll(item1Task, item2Task, item3Task);

async Task<Z> LocalGetItem3(Task<X> item1Task)
{
    X item1 = await item1Task;
    return await _service.GetItem3(item1);
}
```

The [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) `LocalGetItem3` is an example of `async`/`await` composition.

Obviously the operations `_service.GetItem1` and `_service.GetItem3` will run sequentially, the one after the other, because the second depends on the result of the first. In case the `_service.GetItem1` fails, the task `allTasks` will contain the same exception twice in its [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property. This is because the tasks `item1Task` and `item3Task` will both fail with the same error.

Comment: What about `.ContinueWith()` would that be an option?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen No bad idea, much better to just use `await` which sorts out unwrapping and correct exception handling.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the `ContinueWith` is awkward, because you have to deal with all three possible statuses of the antecedent task. It would be lovely if the tasks were equipped with a `ContinueWithResult`/`Then` extension method, having as parameter a lambda with *the result* of the antecedent task instead of the task itself. Unfortunately [we don't have this luxury](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692 "[API Proposal]: Then or ContinueWithResult extension method for Task").